# Win Service keeps stopping The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception

Tags: .net, service, windows-services

I have a db transfer app which runs with win service. It keeps crashing at random times there are 2 logs at the event viewer.
First log-
Application: XXX.XXX.WindowsService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code eedfade, exception address 75313F12
Stack:
Second Log
Faulting application name: XXX.XXX.WindowsService.exe, version: 2.23.401.0, time stamp: 0x64a41849
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.17763.3287, time stamp: 0xd3d15282
Exception code: 0x0eedfade
Fault offset: 0x00123f12
Faulting process id: 0x93a8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9ae7a6eef85ed
Faulting application path: C:\XXX\XXX\XXX.XXX.WindowsService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a63c9f59-4d3f-42ad-9426-9266ec0e85f1
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

I couln't find any other logs related to this problem. I'm thinking it was .net compability issue but i cant be sure im lost pls help :(